# publish() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, function, ceilometer

I am working with ceilometer python API and publishing data to pubnub. not sure what is meant by this error.

This is the part of code that is causing the problem i think,

```
def init_Data(data, channel):
  cpu_sample = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='cpu_util')
  for each in cpu_sample:
    timetamp = each.timestamp
    volume =  each.counter_volume
    volume_int = int(volume)
    data_volume ={'value': volume_int}
    data=json.dumps(data_volume)
    print (data)


pubnub.publish(channel='orbit_channel', callback= init_Datar)
```

Comment: apparently you are giving `publish` only `two` arguments, `channel and callback`. It needs one more to function

Comment: @ThePredator: No, `self` is implicit and also counted. However, the function takes 2 _positional_ arguments, and those are missing.

Comment: @DanielDarabos: What do positional arguments mean?

Comment: `f(1, 2)` -- those are positional arguments. `f(x=1, y=2)` -- those are keyword arguments. See also the Python documentation.

Answer (score 5):

> publish() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)

Such a terrible error message! One point of confusion is that `self` is also counted as an argument, even if it's not explicitly provided.

So you need to provide 2 arguments. And you did! But you need to provide the 2 *required* arguments, while you only provided 1 required and 1 *optional* argument. Check the API docs for `pubnub.publish()` to see what you're missing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This makes things clear but at API docs for pubnub the function is constructed with 2 kayword arguments. http://www.pubnub.com/docs/python/data-streams-publish-and-subscribe

Comment: You can provide the positional arguments via keywords too, but you _must_ provide them somehow. You're not providing the second positional argument, which is `message`.

Answer (score 1):

While Daniel provided a good explanation, I wanted a minimalist example and was able to come up with this:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, arg1, arg2=None):
...         pass
... 
>>> Foo(arg2=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

So two arguments are provided (`self` and `arg2`), but it's saying at least 2 *positional* arguments are required (`self` and `arg1`). So `Foo(arg1=1)` would work, as would `Foo(1, 2)` and `Foo(1, arg2=2)`.